# Tensorflow gradients: without automatic implicit sum

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

In tensorflow, if one has two tensors `x` and `y` and one want to have the gradients of `y` with respect to `x` using `tf.gradients(y,x)`. Then what one actually gets is :

```
gradient[n,m] = sum_ij d y[i,j]/ d x[n,m]
```

There is a sum over the indices of y, is there a way to avoid this implicit sum? To get the whole gradient tensor `gradient[i,j,n,m]`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my work around just taking the derivative of each component (as also mentionned by @Yaroslav) and then packing them all together again in the case of rank 2 tensors (Matrices):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def twodtensor2list(tensor,m,n):
    s = [[tf.slice(tensor,[j,i],[1,1]) for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
    fs = []
    for l in s:
        fs.extend(l)
    return fs

def grads_all_comp(y, shapey, x, shapex):
    yl = twodtensor2list(y,shapey[0],shapey[1])
    grads = [tf.gradients(yle,x)[0] for yle in yl]
    gradsp = tf.pack(grads)
    gradst = tf.reshape(gradsp,shape=(shapey[0],shapey[1],shapex[0],shapex[1]))
    return gradst
```

Now `grads_all_comp(y, shapey, x, shapex)` will output the rank 4 tensor in the desired format. It is a very inefficient way because everything needs to be sliced up and repacked together, so if someone finds a better I would be very interested to see it.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way. TensorFlow 0.11 `tf.gradients` implements standard reverse-mode AD which gives the derivative of a scalar quantity. You'd need to call `tf.gradients` for each `y[i,j]` separately

Comment: this answer is deprecated, as for tf2.7 (and maybe earlier versions too), see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

for future readers:

Tensorflow has made some advancements, and as for tf2.7 (and maybe even earlier versions) **the answer to this questions is to use tf.GradientTape.jacobian**

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#jacobians